# Drop/Down element for every element (Angular 4)

Tags: html, angular, dropdown

I want to create drop/down element for every elements in array:

```
  <div *ngFor="let hotel of hotels">
    <div>Photo</div>
    <div>{{ hotel.name }}</div>
    <div><button (click)="changeIsShohToTrue()" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i></button></div>

    <div *ngIf="isShow">Additional information</div>
  </div>
```

The main idea is when click on button system drop/down div with additional information for element click.

In my implementation open/close all additional div, how implement drop/down div only for element click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `isShown` on each hotel object, meaning that you set `hotel.isShown =true` in your function and then change the condition accordingly: `*ngIf="hotel.isShown"`

Comment: Good approach, but in this approach need change model

Answer (score -1):

You can add boolean field "isShowAddInfo" to the hotel model, change

`<div *ngIf="hotel.isShowAddInfo">Additional information</div>`

, and change onClick event handler to

`(click)="changeIsShohToTrue(hotel)`

In handler just toggle "isShowAddInfo".